# Remix OS running in Virtual Box under Ubuntu, how to share files?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, android, shared-folders

I have a Remix OS virtual machine. The host is Ubuntu. How can I share files between the guest and the host?

The best thing would be to have a *shared folder* if it's possible.

I have tried Airdroid, but it ends up using the Internet to transfer files.

Yes, I contemplated posting this to Android Enthusiasts and Ask Ubuntu, but I decided on U&L. Both the guest and the host are Linux-based and Virtual Box is well known to U&L users.

Comment: Use NFS. An NFS server on the host sharing to the guest.